# How to create a folder using java in any drive available except for c drive

Tags: java

I need to create a folder using java and in any drive except for c drive.
if there are three systems with different drives, i want to have same code for all these systems creating the folder in any drive available except for c drive in windows using java code

Comment: Read about `java.nio`

Comment: Your question is unclear.  How do you specify the path for the directory?  The drive?  What if the user specifies a path with a drive letter in it?  What should happen if the parent directory doesn't exist?

Comment: What if the path is relative?  What if it is absolute but doesn't include a drive letter?

Answer (score 0):

**Code to create folder according to drive letter:**

```
  public class makeFolder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String location = "D:/abc";
        // split the location value
        String[] values = location.split(":");
        // check here the drive letter.
        if(!values[0].equalsIgnoreCase("C") && !values[0].equals("")) {
            Path path = Paths.get(location);
            if (!Files.exists(path)) {
                try {
                    Files.createDirectories(path);
                    System.out.println("Success");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //fail to create directory
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Hope

This helps :)

Comment: Problem: what if `values[0].equals("")`?  That could happen for a relative or absolute path.

Comment: @StephenC I missed that condition. I have updated it. The code should ignore that values[0].equals("") for a relative or absolute path. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes .... but then you are not testing that the directory is not created on the C: drive!  This problem is more difficult than it seems.  We need to wait for the OP to clarify the question before answering it.

Comment: But she mentioned "any drive available except for c drive".

Comment: I read that.  But every file system is associated with a drive, even if you don't include it in the pathname.   If the pathname doesn't include a drive letter, that doesn't mean that the directory won't be on the C: drive.